# jQuery scrollTop is incorrect by the height of a slideUp div

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, scrolltop, slideup

I have a series of news items (alerts and announcements, to be precise), each individually wrapped inside their own `<div>` tags, set to hide everything but their headline on page load. On clicking any headline (`h2`) that individual item's details reveal (`slideDown`), and any other open items collapse (`slideUp`). Thus only one news item is viewable at a time. All good.

I also have my code set to `scrollTop` to the top of the recently clicked div when the window width is tablet sized or less (767px). *This only works partially.*

I know what the problem is, but not the solution.

The problem is that when I click a different news item, it's scrollTop coordinates are off by the height of the div that's being auto-closed. I've banged my head enough, and the solution's probably simple, but I'm not coming up with it.

The page is live here: http://northqueensviewhomes.com/announcement-test

Remember to make your page width less than 767px and refresh (you'll see the layout respond when you're small enough, then click around a few of the top alert items and you'll eventually see one of them scroll way too high, or even *down* instead of up to the top of the `$this` div.

Here's my jQuery:

```
if ($('#bboards').length) {

  /* Page Load Cleanup */ 
  $('.announcement_item h2 + div,.alert_item h2 + div').hide().removeClass('toggler');
  $('.moreText').removeClass('hidden');

  function hideAll() {
    $('.announcement_item h2, .alert_item h2').removeClass('toggler').children('.moreText').fadeIn('fast').end().next('div').slideUp('fast');
  }

  $('.announcement_item h2,.alert_item h2').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'cursor': 'pointer',
      'color': '#BC2E34',
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).css({
      'cursor': 'default',
      'color': 'black',
    });
  }).click(function() {
    if ($('.toggler').length) {
      var previouslySelected = $('.toggler').parent('div').height();
      alert(previouslySelected);
    } else {
      var previouslySelected = 0;
      // alert(previouslySelected);
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('toggler')) {
      hideAll();
      $('.toggler').removeClass('toggler');
      $(this).children('.moreText').fadeIn('fast'); //this is the "click to read more… text on the link"
      if ($(window).width() <= 767 {
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($(this).parent('div.well').offset().top - 13)
         }, 2222, 'easeInOutExpo');
      }
    } else {
      hideAll();
      $(this).addClass('toggler').next('div').slideDown('fast', 'easeInOutQuad');
      $(this).children('.moreText').hide(); //this is the "click to read more… text on the link"
      if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($(this).parent('div.well').offset().top - 13)
         }, 2222, 'easeInOutExpo');
      }
    }
  });
} // <--- End if $('#bboards').length
```

and you can see the HTML live on the page. I've added a bunch of dummy entries just to create page height.

I'm pretty sure that I just need to delay the scrollTop until the `slideUp` is complete, but, again, not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

There are two relatively easy solutions you could try.

1. The first is, as you said, to delay the scrollTop animation:

   ```
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: ($(this).parent('div.well').offset().top - 13)
       }, 2222, 'easeInOutExpo');
   }, 200);
   ```
2. Or, you can record the initial position of every announcement and alert after you hide their contents when the page loads. Change your section labeled `/* Page Load Cleanup */` to the following:

   ```
   /* Page Load Cleanup */ 
   $('.announcement_item h2 + div,.alert_item h2 + div').hide().removeClass('toggler');
   $('.moreText').removeClass('hidden');
   $('.announcement_item, .alert_item').each(function() {
       $(this).data("top", $(this).offset().top);
   });
   ```

   This gives every announcement a data entry that stores its initial position. Then, whenever you need to animate the scrollTop, do the following:

   ```
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: ($(this).parent('div.well').data().top - 13)
   }, 2222, 'easeInOutExpo');
   ```

   Note that this will only work well if **the contents of the announcements and alerts do not change.**

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these did the trick. The calculation for the scrollTop position seems to be happening while the div is expanded, and so misses the target by that amount once the previous div slidesUp. The delay seems to be running concurrently with the other actions. I even increased the amount of the delay to absurd amounts. Always misses the target.

Comment: As well, the each() function you provided does not seem to remedy the situation, though the logic of it looked right when I first read your reply. Not sure why it's not working, but it resulted in just about the same results as the simple offset() function.

Again, your help is much appreciated. Still scratching my head.

Comment: I fixed the first option to use `setTimeout` instead of jQuery's `.delay()`, which can be finicky with effect queues and should only really be used *between animations.* Whoops! Also, my logic was apparently backwards with that second option. The calculations should be made **after** the contents are hidden. I feel kind of stupid for not making that connection, hahah. I made edits to my answer, see if they help.

Comment: Second solution works really smoothly for my custom accordion. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.